# Firefox table-cell and full width absolutely positioned children

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, css-position

I've stumbled upon some unexpected behaviour when testing a layout in Firefox. It seems that when a parent is set to display:table-cell and position:relative, its children do not respect the parent width when positioned absolutely and given 100% width. Instead, the child width is set to the parent's parent width. I've recreated this issue with a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/D6Rch/1/

which is structured as:

```
<div class="table">
  <div class="cell-1">
    <div class="content-1">this must be positioned absolutely</div>
    <div class="content-2">as these divs will be overlapping</div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell-2">
    <div class="advert">fixed width advert</div>
  </div>
</div>

.table { 
  width:600px;
  height:400px;
  border:3px solid black;
  display: table;
  position: relative;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.cell-1 {
  width: auto;
  display: table-cell;
  background: yellow;
  position: relative;
  margin-right:10px;
}

.cell-2 {
  margin-right:10px;
  width: 100px;
  display: table-cell;
  background: pink;
  position: relative;
}

.content-1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  background: lightgreen;
  z-index: 5;
}

.content-2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background: lightblue;
  z-index: 5;
}

.advert {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

It functions as expected in Chrome & Safari, but not on Firefox. Question is, why does this happen? And is there a workaround for this or should I take an altogether different approach?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: You say that they're absolute, but what I see for the cells is position: relative... Is that how it's supposed to be?

Comment: The content within the cells are absolute. The content divs are the children and the cell div (in this case, .cell-1) is the parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug in Gecko.  See the **Gecko Notes** here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

So, you'll have to wrap you content divs in another positioned div. Like so 
http://jsfiddle.net/D6Rch/4/

```
<div class="cell-1">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="content-1">this must be positioned absolutely</div>
      <div class="content-2">as these divs will be overlapping</div>
    </div>
</div>

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
 }
```